# Sink does not receive values when connecting to finished a Publisher

Tags: swift, combine

I'm struggling to understand why no values are received to `sink` in the underlying code.

```swift
func somePublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
   let subject = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
   subject.send(true)
   subject.send(completion: .finished)
   return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

somePublisher()
   .first()
   .sink { _ in
      print("Completed")
   } receiveValue: {
      print("Received \($0)")
   }
   .store(in: &sinks)
```

Output:

> Completed

It looks like values are not received by the publishers down the stream if it was finished before it was connected. Is that right?
How could I fix that if my publisher can finish synchronously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PassthroughSubject` receives a value and passes it along, it doesn't store the value so if you subscribe to it after the value passed through it, you won't receive it.

You can use `CurrentValueSubject`, which will store the latest value and resend it whenever somebody subscribes to it.

All of this is moot if you send `completion: .finished` though. A completed publisher won't send any values to a subscriber because it's completed.

This is your fixed code:

```swift
func somePublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
   let subject = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(true)
   return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

var bag: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

somePublisher()
   .first()
   .sink { _ in
      print("Completed")
   } receiveValue: {
      print("Received \($0)")
   }
   .store(in: &bag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this same problem and I made use of `RunLoop.current` to overcome it...

```
func somePublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
   let subject = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
   RunLoop.current.perform {
       // Delay send/completion until next run loop to give subscribers a chance to subscribe
       subject.send(true)
       subject.send(completion: .finished)
   }
   return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

somePublisher()
   .first()
   .sink { _ in
      print("Completed")
   } receiveValue: {
      print("Received \($0)")
   }
   .store(in: &sinks)
```